# There is an invalid reference to QuickBooks AP Account

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

Our web-based software communicates with our client's desktop Quickbooks using the Web Connector.

For one particular client, my software sent the following QBXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="8.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <BillAddRq>
            <BillAdd>
                <VendorRef>
                    <FullName>ESSENDANT</FullName>
                </VendorRef>
                <APAccountRef>
                    <FullName>AOS Accounts Payable</FullName>
                </APAccountRef>
                <TxnDate>2017-05-15</TxnDate>
                <RefNumber>1111</RefNumber>
                <Memo>United Stationers Invoice for order 1111 on PO# 1111 (SO# 1111)</Memo>
                <ExpenseLineAdd>
                    <AccountRef>
                        <FullName>Cost of Goods Sold:Purchases</FullName>
                    </AccountRef>
                    <Amount>381.83</Amount>
                    <Memo>Items Total</Memo>
                </ExpenseLineAdd>
                <ExpenseLineAdd>
                    <AccountRef>
                        <FullName>Cost of Goods Sold:COGS Freight</FullName>
                    </AccountRef>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                    <Memo>Total charges/fees</Memo>
                </ExpenseLineAdd>
            </BillAdd>
        </BillAddRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

My software received the following response from the client's Web Connector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRs>
        <BillAddRs statusCode="3140" statusSeverity="Error" statusMessage="There is an invalid reference to QuickBooks AP Account &quot;AOS Accounts Payable&quot; in the Bill.  QuickBooks error message: Invalid argument.  The specified record does not exist in the list." />
    </QBXMLMsgsRs>
</QBXML>
```

Our client sent us the following screenshot from his Chart of Accounts:

[image]

What could possibly be going on here?  It is obviously the correct account name and correct account type.

Anyone??

Comment: Can you do the same request through the UI?

If it works, do a BillQuery and see if there is any difference between your request and what was done in the UI.

It is possible this is looking for an Account Number to be included or used instead of a name. (This would be a preferences setting to use the account number.)

Comment: > Can you do the same request through the UI?  
  
I am a programmer for a Software as a Service.  The QuickBooks Program in question belongs to one of our clients half-way across the country.  I cannot touch his UI or alter his .qbw file!  It is not mine, it belongs to HIS company.

Comment: > If it works, do a BillQuery

I do not have any utility program to send arbitrary QBXML requests to someone's web connector.  Furthermore, the web connector does not accept inbound requests!

His web connector is set up to connect to the specific URL in our software.  Our customer would have to add a new .qwc file to his connector to connect to a special test URL for me to do a BillQuery.

We cannot bother our customers to that degree.

Comment: > It is possible this is looking for an Account Number to be included or
> used instead of a name. (This would be a preferences setting to use
> the account number.)

And does that QB preference only apply to the AP account?  Because we've been sending a miriad of InvoiceAdd Requests and ReceivePaymentAdd Requests and they all work just fine using Account Names that do not contain acct numbers.